# What's the canonical way to share modules between projects?

Tags: haskell

Suppose there are three projects A, B and C. The modules in C will be shared by A and B. Because there is no java's CLASSPATH thing, then do we need to use absolute path when importing modules from C ?

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical way is to choose carefully where they should sit in the module hierarchy and make each project into a fully featured [Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/) package, then install them locally so that they're a part of the namespace for your compiler locally.

This way the modules of each are available to any source code you're writing.

If (for example) you use the [leksah](http://leksah.org/) IDE it'll do a lot of the work for you.

Answer (score 8):

I urge you to [cabalise your projects](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/How_to_write_a_Haskell_program).

But if for some reason you don't want to do this, then the nearest thing to the java classpath is [the `-i` switch to ghc](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html#search-path). Note that the current directory needs to appear explicitly in the list.

Answer (score 4):

If by "projects" you mean Cabal packages, the standard thing to do would be to export whatever modules are necessary from C and then have A and B depend on the C and import them. It's not a good idea to have source files in a package directly depend on files that are aren't part of that package.